# Why are some postal codes not provided by place/details (for given place_id) even though they are returned by places/autocomplete

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I try to find a postal code for a given place_id. The place_id was provided by the autocomplete service. The prediction of the autocomplete service shows me a postal code. When calling the details service there is no postal_code in the address components list.

I tried to restrict the autocomplete service to only search for results with postal_code as type in the address components list. But I think there is no restriction for only providing results with postal_code elements.

```
curl -XGET "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=<API-KEY>&input=88400,Biberach"

#Use place_id of first item: ChIJ1Tzt4ZLFm0cRAlQh0MLHBxE

curl -XGET "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=<API-KEY>&placeid=ChIJ1Tzt4ZLFm0cRAlQh0MLHBxE&fields=address_component,type"
```

My expected behavior is to get a postal_code for the result of place/details. But it isn't there.

Can someone explain to me why this is not provided or if there is a good way to restrict the autocomplete call to only provide results with postal code elements in the address components.

Answer (score 0):

If no postal code is returned this could be due to the result spanning over multiple postal codes (e.g. there is no postal code for "Berlin, Germany" since it could be anything from 10xxx to 14xxx).

A simple workaround could be to include a street and a house number while calling the API.